# Finding the correct random seed number in a parallel execution of simulations

Tags: java, random, refactoring

I have a class like this:

```
public class Class implements Runnable {
    ...
    public void run() {

        ArrayList<Integer> simulations = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Random> randomSeedsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int run = 0; run < getNumberOfSimulations(); run++) {
            simulations.add(run);
            Random random = new Random(run);
            randomSeedsList.add(run, random);
        }
        ...
        simulations.parallelStream().forEach(run -> runSimulation(run,...))
    }
}
```

Now, the `runSimulation` does a lot of things, calls/creates other classes, etc. and at many points of execution (even inside on these other classes), this function is called to get the next random number based on the specific run/simulation you are in:

```
rantInt(arg1,arg2,run)
```

rantInt is defined in the class below:

```
public class Util {
    // get random integer between min and max (inclusive)
    public static int randInt(int min, int max, int run) {
        return Class.randomSeedsList.get(run).nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

The thing is that I want every time that I run let say N parallel simulations to have the exact same results for each one and I have got that with this implementation - but it is ugly because I had to pass the `run` variable through lots and lots of functions calls and classes constructors, just so that I will know its value when some function deep in the code from these simulations executes `rantInt`.

My question: Is there a more elegant way to do this? Any other design principle that I miss in this implementation that will get me the same results without having to carry the `run` variable everywhere?

Comment: I don't understand why you bother to have the same random generator used everytime by each simulation. EDIT: test the code and  got your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate the `Random` instance with the current thread executing the simulation. Since there is no 1:1 relationship between simulations and threads, this association should be encapsulated in a dedicated manager class which enforces the initialization and cleanup of the thread local variable and rejects invalid usage:

```
public class RandomManager {
    private static ThreadLocal<Random> RANDOMS = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static void withRandom(Random rnd, Runnable run) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(rnd);
        Objects.requireNonNull(run);
        if(RANDOMS.get() != null) throw new IllegalStateException("nested invocation");
        RANDOMS.set(rnd);
        try {
            run.run();
        }
        finally {
            RANDOMS.remove();
        }
    }
    // get random integer between min and max (inclusive)
    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random r = RANDOMS.get();
        if(r == null) throw new IllegalStateException("not within withRandom(...)");
        return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

That way, each thread currently executing a simulation can be associated with a `Random` instance, whereas attempts to access a `Random` from a thread not executing a simulation are rejected, and a thread may execute multiple simulation one after another, each of them being associated with a different `Random` instance, but you may not nest simulations. Attempts of nested execution are detected and rejected. Another important property is that the thread local value is removed afterwards, so no garbage is left behind, if the threads are reused for other purposes, which applies to the worker threads used by a parallel stream.

The management of `Random` instances is detached from the actual simulation by simply using arbitrary `Runnable`s to describe the action that might ask for local random values.

Then, the using code could be

```
class YourClass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        ArrayList<Random> randomSeedsList = new ArrayList<>();
        int total = getNumberOfSimulations();
        for (int run = 0; run < total; run++) {
            randomSeedsList.add(new Random(run));
        }
        assert randomSeedsList.size() == total;
        IntStream.range(0, total).parallel()
                 .forEach(run -> RandomManager.withRandom(randomSeedsList.get(run),
                                                          ()->runSimulation(run, …)));
    }
}
```

Or, if the integer index only existed to maintain the association with the `Random` instance, which is not necessary anymore, you can simplify this even further:

```
class YourClass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        List<Random> randomSeedsList
            = IntStream.range(0, getNumberOfSimulations())
                       .mapToObj(Random::new)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

        randomSeedsList.parallelStream()
                       .forEach(random -> RandomManager.withRandom(random,
                                                                   ()->runSimulation(…)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Holger, I have been trying to test some of the class functions that use the `randInt` function (I use `mochito` to mock the RandomManager class and Junit5 for the tests) but I always end up getting the `IllegalStateException("not within withRandom(...)")`. Do you maybe know how to properly test such functions? E.g.

Comment: E.g. ```public void fun() { int index = randInt(0,1); return(index) }``` somewhere inside a class that `runSimulation` calls

Comment: @John that’s not enough context to diagnose the problem. Generally, when you mock `withRandom`, you have to make sure that it delegates to the original implementation. Though mocking should not be required here, as the method is already capable of executing the `Runnable` with an arbitrary `Random` instance. Mocking should be the last resort for code not supporting this level of control.